# How to use django commands to feed a db with an external API?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, api

I'm learning django and I want to feed my django db with https://pokeapi.co API so i can make a drop down list on HTML with every pokemon name up to date.

fetchnames.py

```
import requests as r


def nameslist():
    payload = {'limit':809}
    listpokemons = []
    response = r.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon', params=payload)
    pokemons = response.json()
    for line in pokemons['results']:
        listpokemons.append(line['name'])
    return listpokemons

### Function that request from API and returns a list of pokemon names (['Bulbassaur', 'Ivyssaur',...)
```

core_app/management/commands/queryapi.py

```
from core_app.models import TablePokemonNames
from core_app.fetchnames import nameslist


class FetchApi(BaseCommand):
    help = "Update DB with https://pokeapi.co/"

    def add_model_value(self):
        table = TablePokemonNames()
        table.names = nameslist()
        table.save()
```

core_app/models.py

```
class TablePokemonNames(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    names = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

i'm pretty sure that i'm missing a lot since i'm still learning to use django and i'm still confuse on how should i use django commands, but, i tried to make a django command with `nameslist()` function and nothing happend on the db, there is something wrong with using a list to feed a db?

Comment: What does the `TablePokemonNames` model look like? Do you want to create an entry for each name?

Comment: @IainShelvington

`class TablePokemonNames(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    names = models.CharField(max_length=100)`

Yes, an entry for each name